# tf.data.Dataset.reduce of SparseTensor elements

Tags: tensorflow

I have a `tf.data.Dataset` object `d`, where each element is an integer `tf.sparse.SparseTensor`, and I would like to sum them, returning a sparse tensor. One way I see is the following:

```
d.reduce(tf.sparse.SparseTensor(tf.zeros([0, 1], tf.int64),
                                tf.zeros([0], tf.int32),
                                dense_shape),
         tf.sparse.add)
```

*Problem:*

How do I construct the `zero` for the `reduce` operation if I do not know the `dense_shape` ahead of time? I know all the sparse tensors in the dataset will have same shape, but it is not statically known. Perhaps it depends on data from which the sparse tensors are constructed, and setting this interactively in eager mode is not a viable option.

Comment: Use `tf.sparse.reduce_sum` to construct the zero for reduce operation even if you don't know the `shape` also. For more information visit the [Tensorflow library](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/reduce_sum).Thanks!